# Flutter App: Android App Link (Deep Linking) not Opening the App on Android Device

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter app and have set up android deep linking to open the app when accessing a specific URL on Android devices. However, the app doesn't open as expected when the URL is accessed, redirecting to the URL instead.

Here's what I've done:

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```xml
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="192.168.1.92:8000" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

I've also added the assetlink.json file in my local server, placed in the .well-known/ folder as follows:

```
[
    {
        "relation": [
            "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
        ],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "com.example.app",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
                "64:FD:70:F8:E1:18:7C:8E:75:4A:66:2B:DC:A1:C0:C7:40:F4:3B:F9:E8:A9:C8:06:63:68:CC:CE:21:A3:80:56"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

However, when I run the following command, it works:

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "http://192.168.1.92:8000"' \
    com.example.app
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue in the context of a Flutter app? Why isn't the app opening when I access the specified URL on an Android device?